# BigQuery API via PHP. useQueryCache = false, not working

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am having trouble with disabling using query cache. I am using BigQuery API using PHP.

In: `object(Google_Service_Bigquery_QueryRequest)`
I have:

```
["useQueryCache"]=> bool(false)
```

But in: `object(Google_Service_Bigquery_QueryResponse)`
I have:

```
["cacheHit"]=> bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work now. Can anyone on the BigQuery team at Google confirm there was an API bug?